# Polymer 1.0 paper-menu-button horizontalAlign and horizontalOffset not working

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I have the following code:

```
<paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar">
    <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
    <div class="app-name">Dashbord</div>
    <span class="flex"></span>
    <paper-menu-button horizontalAlign="right" horizontalOffset="20" verticalAlign="top" verticalOffset="50">
        <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
            <paper-item>Share</paper-item>
            <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
            <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
        </paper-menu>
   </paper-menu-button>
</paper-toolbar>
```

The menu button works as expected but the drop down `horizontalAlign` and `horizontalOffset` properties do not take effect.

The only way I got the drop down menu to work is by hard coding the values in the element definition:

```
<iron-dropdown
  id="dropdown"
  opened="{{opened}}"
  horizontal-align="right"
  vertical-align="top"
  horizontal-offset="50"
  vertical-offset="20"
  open-animation-config="[[openAnimationConfig]]"
  close-animation-config="[[closeAnimationConfig]]"
  no-animations="[[noAnimations]]"
  focus-target="[[_dropdownContent]]">
  <paper-material class="dropdown-content">
    <content id="content" select=".dropdown-content"></content>
  </paper-material>
</iron-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice the difference between your definition `horizontalOffset="20"` and the working one `horizontal-offset="50"`?

Try changing your code to

```
<paper-menu-button
    horizontal-align="right"
    horizontal-offset="20"
    vertical-align="top"
    vertical-offset="50">
```

[See property name to attribute name mapping](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#property-name-mapping).

> Attribute names with dashes are converted to camelCase property names
>   by capitalizing the character following each dash, then removing the
>   dashes. For example, the attribute first-name maps to firstName.